# c++ how does cout print a char*

Tags: c++, pointers, cout

In the code below, the function `getName()` returns a `char *`. I would of thought that it should (it also can) return a `string`. How does `cout` correctly print it to the console if it is just a pointer to the first char?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Base
{
protected:
    int m_value;

public:
    Base(int value)
        : m_value(value)
    {
    }

    const char* getName() { return "Base"; }
    //string getName() { return "Base"; }
    int getValue() { return m_value; }
};


int main()
{
    Base base(5);
    std::cout << "Base is a " << base.getName() << " and has value " << base.getValue() << '\n';


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Allow me to refer you to our selection of [book recommendations...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Consider learning from a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). C-strings (a.k.a. null-terminated strings) are delimited with `\0` character. `std::cout` just keeps printing it, until it reaches such a character.

Comment: Because the string literals have an implicit null terminator in them. So when sent to the output stream it knows when to stop sort of speaking.

Comment: There is a special `operator<<` overload for `const char*` that displays the string instead of just the pointer.

Comment: There is an `operator<<()` function or method which takes the pointer as a parameter and iterates over it until it finds a null character and stops. This is just like `printf()`.

Comment: The `const char *` parameter is a *copy* of the pointer returned by `getName`. It can be incremented, independent of `Base`, and dereferenced. The implementation might look something like `for ( ;*str; ++str) { stream.put(*str); }`

Answer (score 2):

`cout` and friends consider the type `char *` to be a [C-string](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_strings.htm).

If you want it to print a single character referred by a pointer, you have to [dereference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereference_operator) it first, so `cout` gets the `char` type. Or, since a C-string is an array of chars, you can use its 0<sup>th</sup> item.

```
const char* myString = "Hello";
cout << "string:    " << myString << endl
     << "*string:   " << *myString << endl
     << "string[0]: " << myString[0] << endl;
```

gives ([check it online](https://ideone.com/vQVkNJ)):

```
string:    Hello
*string:   H
string[0]: H
```